# How to insert value in a variable Json href attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, json

One question I wanted to put a variable inside href link not using code, which is in direct link creation.

The example is below:

```
<a href="http://websro.correios.com.br/sro_bin/txect01$.QueryList?P_LINGUA=001&P_COD_UNI=" + [CODIGO_RASTREAMENTO] targert="_blank">código de rastreamento</a>
```

variable [CODIGO_RASTREAMENTO] comes from a Json file this on the server side.

Note: I can not use *scripts*.

Comment: I can not use tags <script> scripts </ script> 
has to be something inline <a href="link_file + [CODIGO_RASTREAMENTO]">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For inline your choice is really limited. For example you can use "onmouseover" event to replace placeholder with variable value on the fly.

Let's say you have following link

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/search?q=CODIGO_RASTREAMENTO" target="_blank">
  Search
</a>
```

In that case "CODIGO_RASTREAMENTO" is just a placeholder. At some point variable `CODIGO_RASTREAMENTO` gets assigned, e.g.

```
var CODIGO_RASTREAMENTO = 'stackoverflow';
```

You can modify the above link to

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/search?q=CODIGO_RASTREAMENTO"
   onmouseover="this.href = this.href.replace('CODIGO_RASTREAMENTO', CODIGO_RASTREAMENTO)" 
   target="_blank">
      Search
</a>
```

It replaces placeholder with a real value, so when you actually click the link - value takes effect.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5v2S9/**